# Wiring a 3ph motor with a VFD, motor has thermostat wires (overheat protection), where should these go in the VFD wiring scheme?

Tags: vfd

Motor is 1hp, 3ph, doerr LR22132 style with thermostat protection.  VFD will be single phase 120v input, 3ph 240v output.